# Plotly updatemenus clipping into subplots

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly figure with two subplots.  I want the top subplot to use the updatemenus to switch between different options.  The bottom plot is static.  The issue I have is the first time a new option is selected the top chart expands to become as tall as both charts.  Simplified code below.

Some other things I've tried:

- changing the method to `restyle` fixes the expanding top subplot but then doesn't change the axis title, ideally I can have both.
- I've tried a few combination of other yaxis parameters (anchor, position) but nothing has worked so far.  I'm guessing this is where the solution is but I'm not certain.
- I tried putting row_heights into the second argument of `args` but that had no effect

It seems like the row_height is defaulting back to 1 on an update but I can't find the parameter to change it.  Picture of what it looks like after changing from square to cube below.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd


def main():
    figure = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 8, 1.41], [3, 9, 27, 1.73]], columns=['num', 'square', 'cube', 'sqrt'])

    figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['num'], y=df['square']), row=1, col=1)
    figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['num'], y=df['sqrt']), row=2, col=1)
    figure.update_yaxes(title='square', row=1, col=1)
    figure.update_yaxes(title='sqrt', row=2, col=1)

    buttons = []
    options = ['square', 'cube']
    for option in options:
        buttons.append({'method': 'update',
                        'label': option,
                        'args': [{'y': [df[option]]},
                                 {'yaxis': {'title': option}},
                                 [0]
                                 ]
                        })
    figure.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(buttons=buttons, direction='down')])
    figure.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making a comment that just shows how you don't have to be all that smart to answer questions on SO...sorry about that. Obviously, you're right. I had to delete that comment, my pride just couldn't handle it!!

Either way, the solution to your original question.

For restyling `y`, you've nailed it.

For `relayout` of the `yaxis`, you need to know a few things:

- What did Plotly name the `yaxis`? Chances are, if it's the second listed graph, the y-axis is named `yaxis2`.
- What is the `yaxis.domain` for the affected graph?
- Is there a title to begin with? (You need to have a title to change it. The title can be `""`, though.)

For both of these needs, you can use the figure you've already created to get the information. Unless it's an overwhelmingly complicated setup, it's a safe guess on the name of the `yaxis`.

To get the domain that you need for the buttons, create an object with that information before creating the buttons. You only need to collect the `domain` of the `yaxis` that is getting the new title.

```
y1dom = fig.layout.yaxis.domain 
y2dom = fig.layout.yaxis2.domain
```

Here's a simple but effective example that works. This updates the graph at the bottom.

```
x, y = ([1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2])
fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1, shared_xaxes = True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = x, y = y, mode = "lines"), row = 1, col = 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y = y, x = x, mode = "markers"), row = 2, col = 1)

y2dom = fig.layout.yaxis2.domain # collect the domain assigned in the subplot

fig.update_yaxes(title_text = "y-axis title of bottom subplot", row = 2, col = 1)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus = [go.layout.Updatemenu(
    buttons = list([
        dict(
            args = [{'y':[[1, 1, 1]]}, 
                    {'yaxis2':{'title': 'title', 'domain': y2dom}}, 
                    [1]],
            method = 'update', label = 'update 1'),
        dict(
            args = [{'y':[[1, 3, 2]]},
                    {'yaxis2':{'title': 'different title', 'domain': y2dom}},
                    [1]],
            method = 'update', label = 'update 2')
        ])
)])
fig.show()
```

The images are the original data, update 1, then update 2.

[image]

[image]

[image]